# Custom Access check for module route

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm working on module that should behave as API endpoint.

I created Controller which handler POST & GET requests from external system, but I need to add user authentication so only authenticated user can acccess these endpoints.

My **mymodule.routing.yml**:

```
mymodule.show_content:
  path: 'api/getContent'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ContentController::getContent'
    _format: hal_json
  requirements:
    _method: 'POST'
    _custom_access_check: 'TRUE'
```

My **mymodule/src/Access/CustomAccessCheck.php**:

```
class CustomAccessCheck implements AccessInterface
{
    public function access(AccountInterface $account)
    {
        return ($account->hasPermission('access content')) ? AccessResult::allowed() : AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
}
```

My **mymodule.services.yml**:

```
  mymodule.custom_access_check:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _custom_access_check }
```

I created a user called REST with `REST` role. I gave him 'access content' permission and tried to make request with Postman using POST method and following headers:

```
{
    Content-Type: application/hal+json,
    Authorization: Basic <base64_encoded user:pass>
    X-CSRF-Token: token obtained from <page_url>/rest/session/token
}
```

When I make request with admin user, I see in recent logs, that admin access the route /api/getContent but access was denied. When I use my REST user it logs as anonymous user. Even when I log the status of authentication inside **CustomAccessCheck::access** function I see that user is authenticated with *TRUE*

I need to keep this authentication separated (out of controller, in service or something) because I need to authenticate every request (re-use auth) so only internal users can use API (and not everyone with URL). I don't understand what is missing and why only my admin user is recognized by drupal and the REST user not.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace:

```
requirements:
  _method: 'POST'
  _custom_access_check: 'TRUE'
```

With:

```
requirements:
  _method: 'POST'
  _permission: 'access content'
```

Any then remove your CustomAccessCheck code

Comment: When I do so, I can access the page only if I have 'access content' permission. That's ok when I'm logged in as **Admin**. But I want to access the page from my third-party app using drupal credentials in _POST request_